# Applying accelometer movement in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using corona sdk to move a plane using tilt. But my game is in landscape. I am not sure where the problem is in my code. The movement seems to be weird. I understand the problem is because the game is in landscape. Someone help me out with the solution.
Here is the code that I used

```
function onTilt(event)      
    motionx = 20*event.xGravity
    motiony = 20*event.yGravity 
    plane.x=plane.x+motionx
    plane.y=plane.y-motiony 
end
Runtime:addEventListener("accelerometer", onTilt)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by weird movement, can you be more specific? Try adding `motion.y` to `plane.y` instead of subtracting it. That might be the cause of your weird movement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
-- Create an object

local object = display.newImage("indicator.png")

object:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
object.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
object.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5 + 50

-- Accelerometer Events

local accObject = {}
local centerX = display.contentWidth * 0.5

function accObject:accelerometer(e)
    object.x = centerX + (centerX * e.xGravity)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("accelerometer", accObject)
```

Please try to use the above method as per your requirement. I hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.... In fact the solution was simple... Thanks everybody.

```
    motionx = 20 * event.yGravity 
    motiony = 20 * event.xGravity

    plane.x=plane.x-motionx
    plane.y=plane.y-motiony
```